# fragment is already active while calling Fragment.setArguments()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating an activity which shows a list of videos(VideoListingActivity) depending on the parameters passed from the parent activity.my I am trying to pass the bundle passed to VideoListingActivity to its child fragment so that it can fetch the related data from database and display it on the activity. I am trying to use Fragment.setArguments() to pass the bundle to fragment but getting the below error .

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rrdtech.vidyavaan.android/com.rrdtech.vidyavaan.android.VideoListingActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active
```

I think the fragment is attached to activity post to onCreate() so should this error even be raised ?

Below are the codes for my activity and fragment

VideoListingActivity.java

```
 public class VideoListingActivity extends ActionBarActivity   implements   FilterFragment.OnFilterItemSelectedListener,
    android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
{

 public VideoListFragment videoListFragment;
 private android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView;
 private  Context context;
private Bundle bundle;
private String listBy;
private String subjectId;
private String levelType;
private FragmentTransaction ft;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_listing);

   // videoListFragment=new VideoListFragment();
    videoListFragment= (VideoListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frg_video_listing_video_listing_fragment);
     ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    context=this;
    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    videoListFragment.setArguments(bundle);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_video_listing, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.item_action_search);

    //SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
     searchView = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.item_action_search).getActionView();
    setupSearchView(menuItem);
    //searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public  void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem)
{

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if(searchManager != null)
    {
        SearchableInfo info = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(info);
    }
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onFilterItemSelected(String filterId) {
    videoListFragment.filterSelectedAction("filter id is "+filterId);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    CommonFunctions commonFunctions = new CommonFunctions();
    commonFunctions.showProgressDialog(context,"getting data","bringing");

    ft.replace(R.id.frg_video_listing_filter_fragment,videoListFragment);
    ft.commit();
    commonFunctions.dismissProgressDialog();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    return false;
}
}
```

VideoListingFragment.java

```
public class VideoListFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView videoListView;
private Context activityContext;
private VideosListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<Video> videosList;
private  Bundle b;
private String listBy;
private String subjectId;
private String levelType;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    activityContext = activity.getApplicationContext();
    b=new Bundle();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_fragment,container,false);


}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    b= getArguments();
    listBy = b.getString(VidyavaanGlobal.listBy);
    Log.d("list by ",listBy);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}


public void filterSelectedAction(String x)
{
    Log.d("passed is ", x);
}

public void fillData()
{
    videosList.add(new Video("chapter1","title1", "pragyan public school", "pawan saraskar", "Chemistry", "Advance", "abcd url", "21", "5/6/2015", "thumbnail url"));
    videosList.add(new Video("chapter2","title2","pragyan public school","pawan saraskar","physics","Advance","abcd url","21","5/6/2015","thumbnail url"));
    videosList.add(new Video("chapter3","title3","pragyan public school","pawan saraskar","english","Advance","abcd url","21","5/6/2015","thumbnail url"));
    videosList.add(new Video("chapter4","title4","pragyan public school","pawan saraskar","Chemistry","Advance","abcd url","21","5/6/2015","thumbnail url"));
    videosList.add(new Video("chapter5","title5","pragyan public school","pawan saraskar","Chemistry","Advance","abcd url","21","5/6/2015","thumbnail url"));
    videosList.add(new Video("chapter6","title6","pragyan public school","pawan saraskar","Chemistry","Advance","abcd url","21","5/6/2015","thumbnail url"));
    videosList.add(new Video("chapter7", "title7", "pragyan public school", "pawan saraskar", "Chemistry", "Advance", "abcd url", "21", "5/6/2015", "thumbnail url"));
}


public void displayVideoList(boolean searchReqeust )
{

}

public void displayVideoList(String pListBy, String pValue)

{



    listAdapter = new VideosListAdapter(activityContext,videosList);
    videoListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

public void displayVideoList(String subjectId, String videoType, String VideoLevel)
{

}


}
```

can one please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that you have added your fragment in the layout xml of the activity because of which you fragment has been already added and hence you cannot call setArguments.

Comment: yes i have added the fragment in the xml layout of activity ? doest the cycle not followed when adding via XML layout like onCreate() -> AttachFragment() ?

Comment: i removed the fragment from xml layout and added it dynamically in the activity. It sorted out the issue

Comment: glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Official Android development Reference:

> Public void setArguments (Bundle args) Supply the construction
>   arguments for this fragment. This can only be called before the
>   fragment has been attached to its activity; that is, you should call
>   it immediately after constructing the fragment. The arguments supplied
>   here will be retained across fragment destroy and creation.

Your fragment is already attached to its activity i suggest you to use your own method, you don't need `setArguments`!

create your own `setUIArguments(Bundle args)` inside the fragment class and update the fragment UI inside this method

You will call this method in this way:

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Detailfragment detailFragment = (Detailfragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(detailFragmentID);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(BUNDLE_KEY, obj);// passing this object

        detailFragment.setUIArguments(bundle); /* your new method */
}
```

in your **fragment class**

```
public void setUIArguments(Bundle args) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            /* do your UI stuffs */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this way. the problem is that whenever i tried to re attach the list adapter to show results according to new parameters . it threw NullPointer exception on videoListView

Comment: does your findFragmentById returning null?

Comment: yes it was.. now its working . what i did is .... in XML of activity i added framelayout and then added the fragment dynamically. using transaction.replace() method. Thanks for your suggestion...

Comment: one doubt is i want to use the same fragment to show the results of a searchvideo query in the same activity... do you think it can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

call

```
bundle = new Bundle();
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
videoListFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

before

```
 ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

line.

Answer (score 0):

try to call `ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();` after adding bundle as arguments.